# How to get the child span text using neighbor element name using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding the drop down name dynamically and uniquely. But facing problem to getting the text of a span using the neighbor or main drop down name as following div..

```
<div class="SumoSelect" tabindex="0">
    <select style="display: none;" class="popupShowOnAll" id="ddlFee" multiple="Multiple" name="ddlFee3923"></select>
    <p class="CaptionCont SlectBox">
      <span>Lender Discount Fee</span>
    </p>  
</div>
```

I have only name of select tag `name="ddlFee3923"` is unique. I want to get the text of span tag (i.e Lender Discount Fee) using the name `name="ddlFee3923"` of `<select>` element.

I have already tried:

```
var a = document.getElementsByName('ddlFee3923');
var b = b.closest('p');
$(b).children(":first").text;
```

but unable to get the text of span. Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is the next sibling's descendant element so use attribute selector to get the element using name, the use .next() and .find()

```js
var el = $('[name="ddlFee3923"]');
var text = el.next().find('span').text();

snippet.log('Result: ' + text)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="SumoSelect" tabindex="0">
  <select style="display: none;" class="popupShowOnAll" id="ddlFee" multiple="Multiple" name="ddlFee3923"></select>
  <p class="CaptionCont SlectBox">
    <span>Lender Discount Fee</span>
  </p>
</div>
```